# MySQL: Update Query using If else

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update the table and I am not known which column is going to update.
Here is the simple example

```
Update tablename
set 
if col1='A' then col1='IA',col2='XXX'
if col3='A' then col3='IA', col4='XXX'
where
(col1='A' and col2='UNKNOWN') or (col3='A' and col4='UNKNOWN')
```

Here either `col1` or `col3` surely contains `'A'`

Please provide me correct query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col1=(CASE WHEN col1 LIKE 'A' THEN col1='IA' ELSE col1 END),
col2=(CASE WHEN col1 LIKE 'A' THEN col2='XXX' ELSE col2 END),
col3=(CASE WHEN col3 LIKE 'A' THEN col3='IA' ELSE col3 END),
col3=(CASE WEHN col3 LIKE 'A' THEN col4='XXX' ELSE col4 END)
WHERE
(col1='A' AND col2='UNKNOWN') OR (col3='A' AND col4='UNKNOWN')
```

Answer (score 0):

And old post, but for those Googlers who stumble upon this. This won't work.
e.g.

```
THEN col1='IA'
```

will return a boolean and set col1 to `1` i.e. true
Instead just return the `'IA'` with `THEN 'IA' ELSE col1 END`

For clarity:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET col1=(CASE WHEN col1 LIKE 'A' THEN 'IA' ELSE col1 END),
col2=(CASE WHEN col1 LIKE 'A' THEN 'XXX' ELSE col2 END),
col3=(CASE WHEN col3 LIKE 'A' THEN 'IA' ELSE col3 END),
col3=(CASE WEHN col3 LIKE 'A' THEN 'XXX' ELSE col4 END)
WHERE
(col1='A' AND col2='UNKNOWN') OR (col3='A' AND col4='UNKNOWN')
```