# SQL update query with IF ELSE

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-update

How do I write the following SQL Query (SSMS)

My Table has 2 columns - ColumnA and ColumnB

```
IF my_table.columnA < 15
  update my_table set my_table.ColumnB = 0
else IF my_table.columnA < 28
  update my_table set my_table.columnB = 1
else IF my_table.columnA < 43
  update my_table set my_table.columnB = 2
else IF my_table.columnA < 60
  update my_table set my_table.columnB = 3
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Update Query using If else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580520/mysql-update-query-using-if-else)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a `case` expression:

```
update mytable
    set columnB = (case when columnA < 15 then 0
                        when columnA < 28 then 1
                        when columnA < 43 then 2
                        when columnA < 60 then 3
                   end)
    where columnA < 60;
```